# How do you sign a header using MAC Access Authentication on Android?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to sign an http header using the MAC Access Authentication on Android. I'm using the IETF draft #2 as located here:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-02 (1)

Using the draft's example, the variables are:

```
   MAC key identifier: h480djs93hd8
   MAC key: 489dks293j39
   MAC algorithm: hmac-sha-1
   Timestamp: 1336363200
   Nonce: dj83hs9s
```

the following is the normalized string:

```
 1336363200\n
 dj83hs9s\n
 GET\n
 /resource/1?b=1&a=2\n
 example.com\n
 80\n
 \n
```

I using the following method to encode the mac header:

```
private String calculateMAC(final String macAlgorithm, final String normalizedString, final String keyString) {
    try {
        final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec((keyString).getBytes("UTF-8"), macAlgorithm);
        final Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(macAlgorithm);
        mac.init(keySpec);

        return Base64.encodeToString(mac.doFinal(normalizedString.getBytes("UTF-8")), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the draft says that the resulting MAC is "`bhCQXTVyfj5cmA9uKkPFx1zeOXM=`". But whatever I'm trying (different encoding, difference library, etc), I always have "`6T3zZzy2Emppni6bzL7kdRxUWL4=`". Why??

---

(1) The latest draft (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-http-mac-03) does not have an example. So it's harder to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same example on two different platforms (php and C#) and it appear that the example is incorrect (it is a draft after all). The correct output really is "`6T3zZzy2Emppni6bzL7kdRxUWL4=`".

[Other have seen the same issue](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg08377.html)